# How to get the sum of the values when the columns have different sizes

Tags: python

I have 42 files containing 42 days' data of 1 variable/profile (i.e. each file has 1 variable and altitude) and I need to calculate the sum and the average of the variable at the same height.

However, the variables/columns in 42 files have different sizes. For example, in file 0.cdf, tdry.shape = 3085 whereas in file 1.cdf, tdry.shape = 3505. How can I add several columns with different sizes and still get the sum from the same altitude?

```
from scipy.io import netcdf
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import numpy
from matplotlib import rc

tdry_sum = np.zeros(3085, dtype = float)
for i in range(0,42):
    path = "/data/{}.cdf".format(i)
    a = netcdf.netcdf_file(path,'r')

    tdry = a.variables['tdry'][:]     #variable
    alt = a.variables['alt'][:]       #altitude

    tdry_sum = try_sum + tdry
```

Comment: How the average of non-existing data is supposed to be calculated? Should it take a 0 instead of a missing value or should that be excluded from the average?

Comment: It should be excluded from the average. And the denominator should minus 1

Comment: Is it the case that altitude always appears in the same order in the files? Can you share the cdf files?